# How to get more than one item with identical html tag on BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am new to BeautifulSoup and I am not that familiar with Html.. But I am learning and I am finding myself some little projects to do. For this one, what I want is to get the football match info from this [site](https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/ligue-1/page-calendrier-resultats/21e-journee), like TeamA Date/time TeamB.

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/ligue-1/page-calendrier-resultats/21e-journee'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

all_result = soup.find('div', class_="grid")

all_pairs = all_result.find_all('div', class_='grid__item')

i = 0
for result in all_pairs:
    i = i + 1
    team_name = result.find('span', class_='TeamScore__nameshort')  
    calendrier = result.find('div', class_='TeamScore__data')

    
    
    print(i)
    print(team_name.text.strip())
    print(calendrier.text.strip())
    print()
```

My problems are:

1. It only grab the first team. Like Nice vs. Rennes, but it only gets "Nice". The Html tags for TeamA and TeamB seem the same to me. I checked `find_all`, but it did not work neither.
2. For whatever reason, the Date/Time it gets are wrong. It shows some completely different dates and time. I don't know why..

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
element = soup.select('div.grid__item')
firstElement = element[0].get_text()
```

Another Example to get an attribute for the following html code:

```
<div class="nextpage">
    <a class="next-story" href="somepage.html">Some Page</a>
    <a class="next-story" href="somepage2.html">Some Page 2</a>
    <a class="next-story" href="somepage3.html">Some Page 3</a>
</div>
```

Code would be:

```
link = soup.select('div.nextpage a.next-story')
href = link[0].get('href')
```

When you print href, it would return 'somepage.html'

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` is indeed the function you are after.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/ligue-1/page-calendrier-resultats/21e-journee'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

all_result = soup.find('div', class_="grid")

all_pairs = all_result.find_all('div', class_='grid__item')

i = 0
for result in all_pairs:
    i = i + 1
    team_names = result.find_all('span', class_='TeamScore__nameshort')
    first_team_name = team_names[0]
    second_team_name =  team_names[1]
    calendrier = result.find('div', class_='TeamScore__data')



    print(i)
    print('{} vs {}'.format(first_team_name.text.strip(), second_team_name.text.strip()))
    print(calendrier.text.strip())
    print()
```

which should output:

```
1
Nice vs Rennes
24 janv.
                    20h45

2
Marseille vs Angers
25 janv.
                    17h30

3
Montpellier vs Dijon
25 janv.
                    20h00

4
Monaco vs Strasbourg
25 janv.
                    20h00

5
Reims vs Metz
25 janv.
                    20h00

6
Brest vs Amiens
25 janv.
                    20h00

7
Saint-Étienne vs Nîmes
25 janv.
                    20h00

8
Lyon vs Toulouse
26 janv.
                    15h00

9
Nantes vs Bordeaux
26 janv.
                    17h00

10
Lille vs Paris-SG
26 janv.
                    21h00
```

`find_all` just returns a list of elements so you will have to use an index to access the element you want (or alternatively, iterate over the list).

As for the dates being different, I haven't looked into it but one reason could be that when you visit the site in your browser, the dates are changed by JS to be in your local timezone. By getting the site with BeautifulSoup, you would be getting the default timezone dates.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your detailed answer!!!!! ♡♡♡ Very clear and the code works. I look at the time as well. I think you are right and it is with the timezone. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :) If my answer worked for you, consider marking it as answering your question so that it can also help future people with this issue :)